# Converting html file to a word doc with python

Tags: python, html, pywin32

I am trying to convert an html file to a word document with python, my code is

```
import win32com.client

word = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')

doc = word.Documents.Add('htmlFile.html')
doc.SaveAs('example.doc', FileFormat=0)
doc.Close()

word.Quit()
```

When I run this I get the error

```
$ python HTMLtoWord.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HTMLtoWord.py", line 5, in <module>
    doc = word.Documents.Add('../htmlFile.html')
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 2, in Add
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Word', "Sorry, we couldn't find your file. Was it moved, renamed, or deleted?", 'wdmain11.chm', 24654, -2146823114), None)
```

Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: Try `doc = word.Documents.Add(os.path.abspath('../htmlFile.html'))`. From experience quite a few years ago, MS Word automation only likes absolute paths.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work

Comment: Then I suggest you check first if `os.path.exists(os.path.abspath('../htmlFile.html'))`